# Как сделать кнопку по центру?

Tags: html, css

```css
.section a {
 color: white;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-decoration: none;
 margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}

.button {
 height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
 <div class="section clearfix">
  <div class="title-text">
   <h2>We are specialist in</h2>
   <h1>Responsive designs, Stationary<br>
    And wordpress Themes</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting<br>industry. Lorem                     Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text.
                </p>
    <div class="button"><a href="#">Button Name</a></div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как только делать кнопке display: inline-block; - то кнопка сразу прилипает к левому краю и никакие text-align: center; не помогают :(

Comment: Что такое сделали, что кнопка навидимая?

Comment: @Sergey не понял Вас.

Comment: Пробовали выполнять свой код? Текст кнопки-ссылки белый, на белом фоне не виден.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как один из вариантов:

```css
.section a {
 color: white;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.title-text {
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
    display: inline-block;
 height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 0 1rem;
}

body {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="section clearfix">
  <div class="title-text">
    <h2>We are specialist in</h2>
    <h1>Responsive designs, Stationary<br>
      And wordpress Themes</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting<br>industry. Lorem                     Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text.
    </p>
    <div class="button"><a href="#">Button Name</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: супер!! огромное спасибо!)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте css хаки)

```
.button{
   height: 50px;
   display:block;
   position: relative;
   border: 1px solid white;
   margin:0 auto; // отцентрирует блок по центру родительского элемента
        }
```

Comment: ни к чему не привело вообще :(

Answer (score 0):

`inline-block` заставляет контейнер (div в данном случае) съёжится до размеров того, что в нём находится. Таким образом `text-align` не годится для выравнивания содержимого внутри `inline-block`. Ибо ему просто некуда двигаться. Размеры-то одинаковые.

Если div шире своего содержимого, то text-align работает.
Но Ваш кнопочный div, когда он нормальный block, растягивается по длине на всю ширину страницы. Поэтому кнопка выравнивается относительно страницы и уезжает правее относительно центра текста.

Можно сузить общий контейнер для текста и кнопки с помощью того же `inline-block`. Он не будет шире текста (предполагаем текст шире кнопки), кнопочный div таким образом тоже по ширине будет как текст, и кнопка теперь выравнивается относительно текста.

```css
.section > div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.button {
  text-align: center;
}

.button > a {
  color: #39739d;
  background-color: #E1ECF4;
  border: 1px solid #96bdd9; 
  padding: 5px; 
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #f4f8fb;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.button > a:hover {
  background-color: #bcd4e6;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div>
    <h2>We are specialist in</h2>
    <h1>Responsive designs, Stationary<br>And wordpress Themes</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting<br>industry. Lorem                     Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text.
    </p>
    <div class="button">
      <a href="#">Button Name</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Понадобилось правильно установить всего два свойства css. Они самые первые.   Остальное для красоты, если это кому-то нравится. Правда есть ещё элемент ubasility. Кнопка работает при нажатии не только по надписи, но и по всей области кнопки. Пользователю не надо быть снайпером.

Comment: отлично, спасибо тебе за выделенное время :)

Comment: Да не за что. Когда у самого ничего не получается, так приятно других поучать:)